# ctrl-x, ctrl-k spelling completion not working on Windows

Tags: autocompletion, microsoft-windows, dictionary, spelling

I use the same configuration on Linux and Windows. This is the config for spelling:

```
" Set dictionary and regenerate spl files on startup
set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/words
set spelllang=en_gb
if has('unix')
  set spellfile=$HOME/.config/vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
elseif has('win32')
  set spellfile=$HOME/vimfiles/spell/en.utf-8.add
endif
for d in glob('spell/*.add', 1, 1)
  if filereadable(d) && (!filereadable(d . '.spl') || getftime(d) > getftime(d . '.spl'))
    exec 'mkspell! ' . fnameescape(d)
  endif
endfor
```

Everything works fine on Linux, and on Windows spellchecking works with `:set spell` even though there is no dictionary location explicitly set above. Where is that Windows dictionary coming from?

However, `C-x, C-k` spelling completion does not work on Windows. It works fine on Linux with a pulldown selection menu of words, but on Windows I get this error message instead:

> -- Dictionary completion (^K^N^P) E486: Pattern not found

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised just after posting this that it works after I comment out this line:

```
set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/words
```

..so I'll set it like this:

```
" Set dictionary and regenerate spl files on startup
set spelllang=en_gb
if has('unix')
  set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/words
  set spellfile=$HOME/.config/vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
elseif has('win32')
  set spellfile=$HOME/vimfiles/spell/en.utf-8.add
endif
for d in glob('spell/*.add', 1, 1)
  if filereadable(d) && (!filereadable(d . '.spl') || getftime(d) > getftime(d . '.spl'))
    exec 'mkspell! ' . fnameescape(d)
  endif
endfor
```

There must be language dictionary files that come with vim on Windows or it uses a system dictionary.

Comment: `/usr/share/dict/words` is not provided by vim. It's provided by the OS (mainly Linux and BSD, but maybe MacOS does as well). `:h dictionary` tells you that if this option is empty, which is the default value, then vim uses the spell file associated with the value of `:h spellang`. If the associated file does not exist and if `spellfile` plugin is active, then vim downloads the required spell file through netrw. I gather this last scenario is applicable to your case.

Comment: You can find all this ^ info from `:h dictionary`, `:h spellang`, and `:h spellfile.vim`.